# Pass back an array from a function (C programing)

Tags: c, function, pointers, reference, header

I am trying to make an image of an vector (exercise from school), so I'm using headers.
There are two files and one funtion.

First I made an vector

```
Vector vector;
GLOBAL_ERROR_CODE = initVector(&vector,3);
if(GLOBAL_ERROR_CODE>0) return printGlobalError();                                          
printf("Vector inited\n");
```

Later trying to print it

```
char * vectorPhotography;
GLOBAL_ERROR_CODE = seeVector( &vector, vectorPhotography );
if(GLOBAL_ERROR_CODE>0) return printGlobalError();
```

So the seeVector funtion it's this

```
int seeVector(Vector * vector, char * vectorPhotography){
     char * vectorStrSize = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
     int ErrorCode = integerToString(vector->size, vectorStrSize);
     if(ErrorCode>0) return ErrorCode;
     char * arrayPhotography = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
     if(ErrorCode>0) return ErrorCode;
     ErrorCode = seeArray(vector->array, arrayPhotography, vector->size);
     if(ErrorCode>0) return ErrorCode;
     if(vectorPhotography) free(vectorPhotography);
     vectorPhotography = (char *) malloc(sizeof("{\nSize:,\nArray:,\n}") + sizeof(arrayPhotography) + sizeof(vectorStrSize));
     if(vectorArray == NULL) return RESERVE_MEMORY_FAIL;
     strcat(vectorPhotography, "{\nSize:");
     strcat(vectorPhotography, vectorStrSize);
     strcat(vectorPhotography, ",\nArray:");
     strcat(vectorPhotography, arrayPhotography);
     strcat(vectorPhotography, ",\n}");
     return 0; 
}
```

So here's the thing, inside the seeVector funtion after the algorim the value of vectorPhotography is this

```
(gdb) print vectorPhotography 
$3 = 0x5555557576f0 "{\nSize:\003,\nArray:[][][],\n}"
```

But when I return to the main function the value is NULL

```
(gdb) print vectorPhotography
$4 = 0x0
```

On running I get this

```
Vector inited
Vector:(null)
```

So my data it's lost, I don't get how to pass back the vector I have been working on, (I need the return for the error codes)

Comment: As you say, it is lost, because you only overwrite the *local copy* of the variable passed by `main`, which is now dangling, because you passed its value to `free`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is pass a reference to the char array `vectorPhotography` so that you can access the updated value after the function call. This would involve changing your function signature to `int seeVector(Vector * vector, char ** vectorPhotography)`, changing your function call to `seeVector( &vector, &vectorPhotography )` and then changing your usages of `vectorPhotography` inside of your function to `*vectorPhotography` so you change the value pointed to by the local parameter

Comment: You were rigth, thanks.

Vector tester
By Oz Pineapple
Vector inited
Vector:{
Size:,
Array:[][][],
}
New problem but I can handdle my self UwU